# Unable to locate package libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to install adobe acrobat reader on my ubuntu machine following [this instruction](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux). I did these steps

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

I got this message:

```
Hit:14 http://oem.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                        
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (169 kB/s)                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://repo.saltproject.io/py3/ubuntu/20.04/amd64/latest focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Next when I ran this step

```
sudo apt install libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0'
```

How can I install adobe  Acrobat Reader on Ubuntu given these errors?